# include() not working on Ubuntu but works on Windows

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

I created a `index.php` page which has many include functions in it like

```
include('header.php');
include('functions.php');
include('connect.php');
```

But none of them is working. My index page just shows a white screen.

I tried it on Windows and it works fine but not on Ubuntu. What's wrong?

Comment: Always try setting error reporting to E_ALL while developing the application so that you can get all the errors

Comment: thanks @Mark M for pointing that.

Comment: @user3649120: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1438393) for how you can enable error reporting.